# Bind de Botão no Tkinter.ttk TreeView em outra Classe

Tags: python, tkinter

## Problema

Como criar uma classe de bind de botão na ttk.Treeview?

## Código de Exemplo

Ao programar a classe principal, que define a TreeView e depois criar outra classe que define bindings e eventos. Não está sendo possível criar estas bindings que estão em outra classe, somente na mesma. Conforme o exemplo a seguir:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk

class clique_bind(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print self.widgetName
        # create the entry on init but does no show it
        self.bind("<Key>", self._qual_tecla)

    def _qual_tecla(self, event):
        print("Tecla: " + event.keysym)

class principal(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        tree = ttk.Treeview()

        tree["columns"] = ("one", "two")
        tree.column("one", width=100)
        tree.column("two", width=100)
        tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
        tree.heading("two", text="column B")
        tree.insert("", 0, text="Line 1", values=("1A", "1b"))
        id2 = tree.insert("", 1, "dir2", text="Dir 2")
        tree.insert(id2, "end", "dir 2", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A", "2B"))
        tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3")
        tree.insert("dir3", 3, text=" sub dir 3", values=("3A", " 3B"))
        tree.pack()

        tree.bind('<Button-3>', self._teste_direito)
        clique_bind(tree)

    def _teste_direito(self, event):
        print("Direito")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = principal(None)
    App.mainloop()
```

Ao realizar a bind do clique do botão direito do mouse na class principal, é possível verificar `print("Direito")`. Mas ao criar a `class clique_bind`, em que captura os botões do teclado em outra Class não é possível.

## Código Completo

O código completo do que está sendo programado, para entender melhor o problema.

Em que o código para listar diretórios utilizado é baseados [na documentação do tkinter](https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py) e o de pesquisar na treeview [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271593/7690982). Algumas alterações foram realizadas.

```
"""A directory browser using Ttk Treeview.

Based on the demo found in Tk 8.5 library/demos/browse
https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py

Search based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271593/7690982
"""


import Tkinter
import ttk
import os
import glob

class SearchableTreeview(ttk.Treeview):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # create the entry on init but does no show it
        self._toSearch = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.focus()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self._toSearch)
        self.bind("<Key>", self._keyOnTree)
        self._toSearch.trace_variable("w", self._search)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self._hideEntry)
        self.entry.bind("<Escape>", self._hideEntry)
        print("init")

    def _keyOnTree(self, event):
        print("keyontree")
        self.entry.place(relx=1, anchor=Tkinter.NE)
        if event.char.isalpha():
            self.entry.insert(Tkinter.END, event.char)
        self.entry.focus_set()

    def _hideEntry(self, event):
        print("hideentry")
        self.entry.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
        self.entry.place_forget()
        self.focus_set()

    def _search(self, *args):
        print("search")
        pattern = self._toSearch.get()
        #avoid search on empty string
        if len(pattern) > 0:
            self.search(pattern)

    def search(self, pattern, item=''):
        children = self.get_children(item)
        for child in children:
            text = self.item(child, 'text')
            if text.lower().startswith(pattern.lower()):
                self.selection_set(child)
                self.see(child)
                return True
            else:
                res = self.search(pattern, child)
                if res:
                    return True


class ListagemDir(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.DirTree()

    def DirTree(self):
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal")

        tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath", "type", "size"),
                            displaycolumns="size", yscrollcommand=lambda f, l: self.autoscroll(vsb, f, l),
                            xscrollcommand=lambda f, l: self.autoscroll(hsb, f, l))

        vsb['command'] = tree.yview
        hsb['command'] = tree.xview

        tree.heading("#0", text="Directory Structure", anchor='w')
        tree.heading("size", text="File Size", anchor='w')
        tree.column("size", stretch=0, width=100)

        self.populate_roots(tree)
        tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.update_tree)
        tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.change_dir)

        # Arrange the tree and its scrollbars in the toplevel
        tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tree.bind("<Button-3>", self._press3)

        searchable = SearchableTreeview(tree)

    def populate_tree(self, tree, node):
        if tree.set(node, "type") != 'directory':
            return

        path = tree.set(node, "fullpath")
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children(node))

        parent = tree.parent(node)
        special_dirs = [] if parent else glob.glob('.') + glob.glob('..')

        for p in special_dirs + os.listdir(path):
            ptype = None
            p = os.path.join(path, p).replace('\\', '/')
            if os.path.isdir(p): ptype = "directory"
            elif os.path.isfile(p): ptype = "file"

            fname = os.path.split(p)[1]
            id = tree.insert(node, "end", text=fname, values=[p, ptype])

            if ptype == 'directory':
                if fname not in ('.', '..'):
                    tree.insert(id, 0, text="dummy")
                    tree.item(id, text=fname)
            elif ptype == 'file':
                size = os.stat(p).st_size
                tree.set(id, "size", "%d bytes" % size)


    def populate_roots(self, tree):
        dir = os.path.abspath('.').replace('\\', '/')
        node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=dir, values=[dir, "directory"])
        self.populate_tree(tree, node)

    def update_tree(self, event):
        tree = event.widget
        self.populate_tree(tree, tree.focus())

    def change_dir(self, event):
        tree = event.widget
        node = tree.focus()
        if tree.parent(node):
            path = os.path.abspath(tree.set(node, "fullpath"))
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                os.chdir(path)
                tree.delete(tree.get_children(''))
                self.populate_roots(tree)

    def autoscroll(self, sbar, first, last):
        """Hide and show scrollbar as needed."""
        first, last = float(first), float(last)
        if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
            sbar.grid_remove()
        else:
            sbar.grid()
        sbar.set(first, last)

    def _press3(self, event):
        print("Tipo de Evento: " + event.keysym)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = ListagemDir(None)
    App.mainloop()
```

## Tentativa

Foi possível realizar o código completo na mesma classe, porém não estou conseguindo em classes diferentes. Pode ser algum erro de fundamentos de classes ou sintaxe Tkinter mesmo.

```
"""A directory browser using Ttk Treeview.

Based on the demo found in Tk 8.5 library/demos/browse
https://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py

Search based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271593/7690982
"""


import os
import glob
import Tkinter
import ttk

class ListagemDir(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.DirTree()

    def DirTree(self):
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical")
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal")

        tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath", "type", "size"),
                            displaycolumns="size", yscrollcommand=lambda f, l: self.autoscroll(vsb, f, l),
                            xscrollcommand=lambda f, l: self.autoscroll(hsb, f, l))

        vsb['command'] = tree.yview
        hsb['command'] = tree.xview

        tree.heading("#0", text="Directory Structure", anchor='w')
        tree.heading("size", text="File Size", anchor='w')
        tree.column("size", stretch=0, width=100)

        self.populate_roots(tree)
        tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.update_tree)
        tree.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.change_dir)

        # Arrange the tree and its scrollbars in the toplevel
        tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nswe')
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tree.bind("<Button-3>", self._press3)

        self._toSearch = Tkinter.StringVar()
        tree.focus()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(tree, textvariable = self._toSearch)
        tree.bind("<Key>", self._keyOnTree)
        self._toSearch.trace_variable("w", self._search)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self._hideEntry)
        self.entry.bind("<Escape>", self._hideEntry)
        print("init")

    def _keyOnTree(self, event):
        print("keyontree")
        self.entry.place(relx=1, anchor=Tkinter.NE)
        if event.char.isalpha():
            self.entry.insert(Tkinter.END, event.char)
        self.entry.focus_set()

    def _hideEntry(self, event):
        print("hideentry")
        self.entry.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
        self.entry.place_forget()
        self.focus_set()

    def _search(self, *args):
        print("search")
        pattern = self._toSearch.get()
        #avoid search on empty string
        if len(pattern) > 0:
            self.search(pattern)

    def search(self, pattern, item=''):
        widgets_children = self.winfo_children()
        #print widgets_children
        for widget_child in widgets_children:
            if isinstance(widget_child, ttk.Treeview):
                tree = widget_child
        children = tree.get_children(item)
        for child in children:
            text = tree.item(child, 'text')
            if text.lower().startswith(pattern.lower()):
                tree.selection_set(child)
                tree.see(child)
                return True
            else:
                res = self.search(pattern, child)
                if res:
                    return True

    def populate_tree(self, tree, node):
        if tree.set(node, "type") != 'directory':
            return

        path = tree.set(node, "fullpath")
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children(node))

        parent = tree.parent(node)
        special_dirs = [] if parent else glob.glob('.') + glob.glob('..')

        for p in special_dirs + os.listdir(path):
            ptype = None
            p = os.path.join(path, p).replace('\\', '/')
            if os.path.isdir(p): ptype = "directory"
            elif os.path.isfile(p): ptype = "file"

            fname = os.path.split(p)[1]
            id = tree.insert(node, "end", text=fname, values=[p, ptype])

            if ptype == 'directory':
                if fname not in ('.', '..'):
                    tree.insert(id, 0, text="dummy")
                    tree.item(id, text=fname)
            elif ptype == 'file':
                size = os.stat(p).st_size
                tree.set(id, "size", "%d bytes" % size)


    def populate_roots(self, tree):
        dir = os.path.abspath('.').replace('\\', '/')
        node = tree.insert('', 'end', text=dir, values=[dir, "directory"])
        self.populate_tree(tree, node)

    def update_tree(self, event):
        tree = event.widget
        self.populate_tree(tree, tree.focus())

    def change_dir(self, event):
        tree = event.widget
        node = tree.focus()
        if tree.parent(node):
            path = os.path.abspath(tree.set(node, "fullpath"))
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                os.chdir(path)
                tree.delete(tree.get_children(''))
                self.populate_roots(tree)

    def autoscroll(self, sbar, first, last):
        """Hide and show scrollbar as needed."""
        first, last = float(first), float(last)
        if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
            sbar.grid_remove()
        else:
            sbar.grid()
        sbar.set(first, last)

    def _press3(self, event):
        print("Tipo de Evento: " + event.keysym)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = ListagemDir(None)
    App.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta está confusa - uma vez que você coloca o código e não diz exatamente o que não funciona.

Mas não existe mágica, ou sintaxe especial do Tkinter - é só Python: Os métodos `bind` do tkinter pedem um parâmetro com um nome de evento e um objeto "chamável" (callable) - é óbvio que se o código tentar usar sempre `self.nome_do_metodo` no segundo parâmetro, o código mesmo está limitando o handler do evento a métodos da classe: tudo o que você precisa é colocar uma referência ao método que quer chamar -

Então, no caso do seu exemplo simplificado - onde você faz:

```
class clique_bind(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print self.widgetName
        # create the entry on init but does no show it
        self.bind("<Key>", self._qual_tecla)

    def _qual_tecla(self, event):
        print("Tecla: " + event.keysym)
```

Se sua intenção é que o método `_qual_tecla` seja associado a um clique na classe `principal`,  dentro da função `__init__` da mesma, depois de atribuir uma instância de  `clique_bind` ao atributo `self.tree`, 
basta fazer:

```
self.bind("<Key>", self.tree._qual_tecla)
```

Não tem segredo algum: o que você quer chamar é o método da instância da outra classe. O que não dá, é, devido a forma como está a pergunta, ter certeza se é isso que você quer.

Além de responder a pergunta, há questões de estilo e práticas no código que poderiam ser comentadas, mas talvez a mais importante seja a sugestão para usar Python 3 em vez de Python 2. Python 2 é uma versão incompatível da linguagem que já não tem atualizações há vários anos, e, em menos de 18 meses, não vai ter mais nenhum suporte oficial. Tudo o que mudaria nesse código seria importar `tkinter` em vez de `Tkinter`, e usar o `print` como função, e não como comando.

Comment: Portanto, se eu quiser usar a Treeview como instância de outra classe. Não é possível deste modo? Pois dentro da `class clique_bind`, esta linha retorna True: `isinstance(self, ttk.Treeview)`. Então não entendo porque não posso usar self para chamar o método da instância da outra classe. Realmente não é possível chamar?

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo o significado de "instância". Pelo menos eu não estou entendendo o que você quer perguntar, já que a frase "usar a Treeview como instância de outra classe"  não faz sentido.

Dê uma conferida aqui, para se certificar de que estamos falando da mesma coisa:  (a página é de Java, mas as definições estão corretas para Orientação a Objetos e são as mesmas que em Python: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/95/pequeno-dicionario-basico-de-orientacao-a-objetos-em-java.aspx )